# MySQL counting number of max groups

Tags: mysql

I asked a similar question earlier today, but I've run into another issue that I need assistance with.

I have a logging system that scans a server and catalogs every user that's online at that given moment. Here is how my table looks like:

```
-----------------
|    ab_logs    |
-----------------
|      id       |
|    scan_id    |
|  found_user   |
-----------------
```

`id` is an autoincrementing primary key. Has no real value other than that.

`scan_id` is an integer that is incremented after each successful scan of all users. It so I can separate results from different scans.

`found_user`. Stores which user was found online during the scan.

The above will generate a table that could look like this:

```
id  |  scan_id  | found_user
----------------------------
1   |     1     |   Nick
2   |     2     |   Nick
3   |     2     |   John
4   |     3     |   John
```

So on the first scan the system found only Nick online. On the 2nd it found both Nick and John. On the 3rd only John was still online.

---

My problem is that I want to get the total **amount of unique users** connected to the server at the **time of each scan**. In other words, I want the aggregate number of users that have connected at each scan. Think counter.

From the example above, the result I want from the sql is:

```
1
2
2
```

EDIT:

This is what I have tried so far, but it's wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(found_user)) FROM ab_logs WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE() GROUP BY scan_id
```

What I tried returns this:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Its 1 ,2, 2 or 1, 2, 1????

Comment: @AnkitBajpai What I want it to return is 1,2,2 (because when Nick disconnected, the scan had still found 2 users until that point). What I tried returned 1,2,1 which is not what I want.

Comment: why is expected resul `1,2,2` ?? first scan - ther was just Nick, second - the were two Nick and John, when 3rd scan - just John! @SMA answer is absolutely correct

Comment: @Alex, no. You must have misunderstood my question. kristof got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should give you the results you are looking for

```
select s.scan_id, count(*) from
  (select distinct
    t.scan_id
    ,t1.found_user 
  from 
    tblScans t
    inner join tblScans t1 on t.scan_id >= t1.scan_id) s
group by
  s.scan_id;
```

Here is [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10973/1/0)
It assumes the names are unique and includes current and every previous scans in the count

Answer (score 2):

Try with group by clause:

```
SELECT scan_id, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY scan_id
```

Comment: @SMA thanks for your input but this will return 1,2,1. What I want needs to show the max amount of unique users logged until that point - regardless if they are online now or not.